# why i can't toggle classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I work on a small to-do list that you can add new task then when you click on the li element it should add 2 classes and remove 1

```
<ul id="myUL" class="todoList">
    <li class='todoList card border-primary'>my li</li>
</ul>
```

this is my js code for toggling classes

```
$( "#myUL" ).children().on("click",function() {  
    $( this ).toggleClass( "checked" );
    $( this ).toggleClass( "border-primary" );
    $( this ).toggleClass( "border-success" );                                                                              
});
```

I included it in the bottom bootstrap.min ,and  jquery-3.3.1.min js files because it dependencies for bootstrap.

But my code works only on the first element. How can I fix it ?

Comment: there is 3 files included in my html file pooper , jquery , and bootstrap

Comment: What do your other <li>'s look like?

Comment: same as this <li> but with different content

Comment: what is popper? I edited to make it proper and you again made it popper

Comment: do you run the JS code each time you add a new element ?

Comment: https://popper.js.org/

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan no but how can i run it every time i make new element

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan i well remove popper is not useful in this page

Comment: @OmarSherif I have answered your question below. that is the best possible explanation for your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works only on the first element because you run the JS code to attach eventlisteners only once. Thus, only the first element has the 'click' eventlistener attached to it.
You can add a listener to the parent and then handle it from there.
Or, alternative is remove all the eventlisteners of all li's and then re-add them using the code you have right now. This is not a good practice but will get the work done.
Here is a example from w3schools

```
// Add a "checked" symbol when clicking on a list item
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
}, false);
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_todolist.asp

Comment: do you mean create a listener to ul and select all children of ui?

Comment: yes, and then you can use the 'target' property to determine in which li tag did the event occour

Comment: @OmarSherif I have edited the question to add relevant code, do accept it as a solution if it works.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
$("#myUL li").click(function() {  
                   $(this).toggleClass("checked");
                   $(this).toggleClass("border-primary");
                   $(this).toggleClass("border-success");

  });
```

Comment: still have the same problem